# In Corona SDK, how do I detect if a ball collides with one of the the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

Part of the game I'm making deals with detecting when a ball collides with the bottom of the screen(thus ending the game). The problem is, I'm having some trouble doing this.

This is my code so far:

```
function gameListeners(action)
    if(action == 'add') then
       ground:addEventListener('collision', display.newImage('end_game_background.png'))
    else
       ground:addEventListener('collision', display.newImage('end_game_background.png'))      
    end
end

function alert() 
    audio.play(loseSnd) 
    gameListeners('rmv') 
    alertView = display.newImage('end_game_background.png', 90, 200) 
    transition.from(alertView, {time = 200, alpha = 0.1}) 
    local scoreTF = display.newText(score.text, 145, 253, 'Futura', 17) 
    scoreTF:setTextColor(255, 255, 255) timer.performWithDelay(100, function() physics.stop() end, 1)      
end
```

If anyone could help, that would be great.

Comment: i forgot this code comes after it:

Comment: function alert()
    audio.play(loseSnd)
    gameListeners('rmv')
    alertView = display.newImage('end_game_background.png', 90, 200)
    transition.from(alertView, {time = 200, alpha = 0.1})
    local scoreTF = display.newText(score.text, 145, 253, 'Futura', 17)
    scoreTF:setTextColor(255, 255, 255)
    
    timer.performWithDelay(100, function() physics.stop() end, 1)
end